# Self Hosted Azure Build agent on windows 2019 server installation

Tags: azure, build, agent

I am trying to setup the build self hosted agent on local windows server. while running config command I am getting following error.

I am trying to setup windows service, this server is domain controller and earlier agent was running very well. I just reconfigured to update the PAT and this error popped up.

Here is more descriptive link about what I have done.

https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2021/04/14/azure-devops-configure-self-hosted-agent-for-azure-pipelines/

ERR  Agent] System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all identity references could not be translated.

Any hint to resolve this issue would be appreciate. I tried other users, and without service same error popups.

Thanks..

1 Created new user. did not worked.
2 Tried with running as batch file, same error poped up.